# Cloning+Dragging model when button is click ROBLOX [LUA]?

Tags: lua, roblox

So I thought of having this for so long, I just don't know where to start. I am new to this language and I keep learning, but kind of hard for me. But I have built my very own custom character which took 2 weeks for me. Anyway, For my question. An example is if I have a button and I click it, a model will be clone and I can drag that model and put it anywhere nearby. What possible method I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

First things first, I suggest for any future questions, you head over to https://scriptinghelpers.org/

now, on to your question, for cloning the model, you should use mouse.Target.Parent:Clone() or the GetTopParent(mouse.Target) function in my function library (which you can get here; http://www.roblox.com/item.aspx?id=244244638)

then deposit the model into workspace and MakeJoints()

the next step is to move the model, this can be tricky, but the simplest method is model:MoveTo(mouse.Hit.p) on mouse.Moved (but that's a little buggy)

Another method for movement would be to use the Handles class, but I'm not really familiar with it, so you'd have to figure that one out on your own.

To make the first method less buggy, I'd suggest something along the lines of

```
model:MoveTo(mouse.Hit.p.X, mouse.Target.Position.Y + (model:GetExtentsSize().Y / 2), mouse.Hit.p.Z)
```

but you'd have to set up the mouse to ignore the model, which I can't really help with.

Comment: "but you'd have to set up the mouse to ignore the model" http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Mouse/TargetFilter

Answer (score 1):

A really good place to start is to search the free models in Studio Toolbox for a 'Dragger Tool' or 'Model Dragger Tool' and then use the script inside to get started creating your own. I have learned to create my own custom draggers by doing this and it is way easier than you may think at first. Once you find a good dragger tool to borrow code from, if you need to enhance it, you can find the dragger api in the Roblox Wiki to help you further customize it to your specific needs.

http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Dragger

EDIT: So here's the first dragger script that showed when I searched. It will drag models and parts but you will have to edit it to meet your requirements using the dragger api. Create a Tool in player.BackPack then create a LocalScript inside the Tool then copy and paste the code below into the LocalScript, and that will get you started.

```
        local Tool = script.Parent

    enabled = true
    local origTexture =     Tool.TextureId
    game:GetService("ContentProvider"):Preload("rbxasset://icons/freemove_sel.png")

    local selectionBox
    local currentSelection
    local currentSelectionColors = {}
    local selectionLasso
    local inGui = false
    local inPalette = false
    local lockTime = 0

    function canSelectObject(part)
        return part and not (part.Locked) and (part.Position - script.Parent.Parent.Head.Position).Magnitude < 60
    end

    function findModel(part)
        while part ~= nil do
            if part.className == "Model" then
                return part
            end
            part = part.Parent
        end

        return nil
    end


    function startDrag(mousePart, hitPoint, collection)
        dragger = Instance.new("Dragger")
        pcall(function() dragger:MouseDown(mousePart, hitPoint, collection) end)
    end

    function collectBaseParts(object, collection)
        if object:IsA("BasePart") then
            collection[#collection+1] = object
        end
        for index,child in pairs(object:GetChildren()) do
            collectBaseParts(child, collection)
        end
    end

    function onMouseDown(mouse) 
        mouse.Icon ="rbxasset://textures\\GrabRotateCursor.png"
        local part = mouse.Target
        if canSelectObject(part) then
            local hitPoint = mouse.Hit:toObjectSpace(part.CFrame).p
            if trySelection(part) then
                local instances = {}
                collectBaseParts(currentSelection, instances)
                startDrag(part, hitPoint, instances)
                return
            end
        end

        --Clear the selection if we weren't able to lock succesfullu
        onMouseUp(mouse)
    end



    function onMouseUp(mouse)
        mouse.Icon ="rbxasset://textures\\GrabCursor.png"
        if dragger ~= nil then
            pcall(function() dragger:MouseUp() end)
            dragger = nil
        end
    end

    function trySelection(part)
        if canSelectObject(part) then
            selectionLasso.Part = part
            local model = findModel(part)
            if model then       
                return setSelection(model)
            else
                return setSelection(part)
            end
        else
            clearSelection()
            return false
        end
    end

    function onKeyDown(key)
        if dragger ~= nil then
            if key == 'R' or key == 'r'  then
                dragger:AxisRotate(Enum.Axis.Y)
            elseif key == 'T' or key == 't' then
                dragger:AxisRotate(Enum.Axis.Z)
            end
        end
    end
    local alreadyMoving
    function onMouseMove(mouse)
        if alreadyMoving then
            return
        end

        alreadyMoving = true
        if dragger ~= nil then
            --Maintain the lock
            if time() - lockTime > 3 then
                Instance.Lock(currentSelection)
                lockTime = time()
            end

            --Then drag
            pcall(function() dragger:MouseMove(mouse.UnitRay) end)
        else
            trySelection(mouse.Target)
        end
        alreadyMoving = false
    end


    function saveSelectionColor(instance)
        if instance:IsA("BasePart") then
            currentSelectionColors[instance] = instance.BrickColor
            if instance.BrickColor == BrickColor.Blue() then
                instance.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Deep blue")
            else
                instance.BrickColor = BrickColor.Blue()
            end
        end

        local children = instance:GetChildren() 
        if children then
            for pos, child in pairs(children) do
                saveSelectionColor(child)
            end
        end
    end

    function setSelection(partOrModel)
        if partOrModel ~= currentSelection then
            clearSelection()
            if Instance.Lock(partOrModel) then
                lockTime = time()
                currentSelection = partOrModel
                saveSelectionColor(currentSelection)
                selectionBox.Adornee = currentSelection
                return true
            end
        else
            if currentSelection ~= nil then
                if time() - lockTime > 2 then
                    --Maintain the lock
                    if not(Instance.Lock(currentSelection)) then
                        --we lost the lock
                        clearSelection()
                        return false
                    else
                        lockTime = time()
                        return true
                    end
                else
                    return true
                end
            end
        end

        return false
    end

    function clearSelection()
        if currentSelection ~= nil then
            for part, color in pairs(currentSelectionColors) do
                part.BrickColor = color
            end
            selectionBox.Adornee = nil
            Instance.Unlock(currentSelection)
        end
        currentSelectionColors = {}
        currentSelection = nil
        selectionLasso.Part = nil
        selectionBox.Adornee = nil
    end

    function onEquippedLocal(mouse)
        Tool.TextureId = "rbxasset://icons/freemove_sel.png"

        local character = script.Parent.Parent
        local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(character)


        inGui = false
        inPalette = false

        mouse.Icon ="rbxasset://textures\\GrabCursor.png"
        mouse.Button1Down:connect(function() onMouseDown(mouse) end)
        mouse.Button1Up:connect(function() onMouseUp(mouse) end)
        mouse.Move:connect(function() onMouseMove(mouse) end)
        mouse.KeyDown:connect(function(string) onKeyDown(string) end)

        selectionBox = Instance.new("SelectionBox")
        selectionBox.Name = "Model Delete Selection"
        selectionBox.Color = BrickColor.Blue()
        selectionBox.Adornee = nil
        selectionBox.Parent = player.PlayerGui

        selectionLasso = Instance.new("SelectionPartLasso")
        selectionLasso.Name = "Model Drag Lasso"
        selectionLasso.Humanoid = character.Humanoid
        selectionLasso.archivable = false
        selectionLasso.Visible = true
        selectionLasso.Parent = game.workspace
        selectionLasso.Color = BrickColor.Blue()

        alreadyMoving = false

    end

    function onUnequippedLocal()
        Tool.TextureId = origTexture
        clearSelection()
        selectionBox:Remove()
        selectionLasso:Remove()
    end


    Tool.Equipped:connect(onEquippedLocal)
    Tool.Unequipped:connect(onUnequippedLocal)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Have a look at this article: [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think my original answer provided enough information but I went ahead and copied over a script anyway. Writing a dragger script for someone from scratch is just too much, but I did provide enough info for anyone to follow, even if the link got changed they would still know exactly what to look for.